# Session is closed! Hibernate JTA JBoss AS 7.1.1

Tags: java, hibernate, session, jboss

Such, we are working with the following technologies:

- PostgreSQL 9.4
- Java SE (jdk7u67)
- jBPM 5.2
- Hibernate 3.5
- JBoss Application Server 7.1.1
- JSF + RichFaces

The application works smoothly in all its functions locally, but when performing a load test the system that want to deploy, when I have more than 3 users simultaneously connected when performing certain tasks, I get the following error:

```
16:12:20,742 INFO  [org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener] (http--192.168.1.11-8080-6) Error performing load command: org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:72) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getBatcher(SessionImpl.java:288) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1812) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntityBatch(Loader.java:1980) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.BatchingEntityLoader.load(BatchingEntityLoader.java:92) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3062) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:434) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:415) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:165) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:223) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:126) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:906) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:874) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:590) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:412) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:139) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:877) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:752) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2232) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2129) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2124) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1149) [hibernate3.jar:]
at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102) [hibernate3.jar:]
at com.comibol.descripcionArchivistica.dao.hibernate.DescripcionArchivoElementoEsencialDAOHibernate.obtenerListaArchivoDescritoElementoEsencial(DescripcionArchivoElementoEsencialDAOHibernate.java:28) [classes:]
at com.comibol.descripcionArchivistica.command.ObtenerListaElementoEsencialcommand.execute(ObtenerListaElementoEsencialcommand.java:31) [classes:]
at com.comibolcore.core.command.CommandHandlerBean.executeCommand(CommandHandlerBean.java:73) [classes:]
at com.comibol.descripcionArchivistica.service.DescripcionArchivisticaServiceImp.obtenerListaElementoEsencial(DescripcionArchivisticaServiceImp.java:89) [classes:]
at com.comibol.scrinia.action.descripcionArchivistica.ListadoDescripcionesArchivoAction.cargarListaElementoEsencialTemportal(ListadoDescripcionesArchivoAction.java:198) [classes:]
at com.comibol.scrinia.action.descripcionArchivistica.ListadoDescripcionesArchivoAction.ini(ListadoDescripcionesArchivoAction.java:101) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1438.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_80]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:117) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:99) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:223) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:147) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.el.parser.AstDeferredExpression.getValue(AstDeferredExpression.java:44) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.el.parser.AstCompositeExpression.getValue(AstCompositeExpression.java:50) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
16:12:20,752 INFO  [stdout] (http--192.168.1.11-8080-6) MESSAGE RUNTIME org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
16:12:20,753 ERROR [com.comibol.auditoria.Log] (http--192.168.1.11-8080-6) Error al registrar log: Session is closed!|StackTrace=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@663f3166|Object=EventLog [idEventLog=143afa2307133881ccc8854c0c6e5ca413a95426, session=null, proceso=java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Throwable.java:459), descripcion=Descripcion=;
ErrorMessage=Self-causation not permitted|
Session is closed!|
```

We are working with two databases, one for application and another for the process engine JBPM.

Hibernate configuration file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/datosdb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">datos</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">datos</property>

    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">datos</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <!--Disable the second-level cache <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>Echo 
        all executed SQL to stdout -->

    <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <!--<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property> -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
    <!--<property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners">false</property> -->
    <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">10</property>
    <property name="connection.autocommit">true</property>

    <!--<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property> -->
    <!--<property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule">org.hibernate:3</property> -->

    <!-- Aqui van las property para hibernate search -->
    <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">org.hibernate.search.store.FSDirectoryProvider
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">C:\indice\metadato</property>

    <!--Modulo Usuarios -->
    <mapping class="com.datos.usuarios.model.Usuario" /> 
    <mapping class="com.comibol.usuarios.model.Rol" /> 
    ...
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The persistence.xml file that works with jbpmdb:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         version="1.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

<persistence-unit name="org.jbpm.persistence.jpa"
                  transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/jbpmDS</jta-data-source>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/JBPMorm.xml</mapping-file>

    <class>org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo</class>
 ...
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                  value="com.datoscore.util.JBPMTransactionManager"/>
    </properties>


</persistence-unit>
<persistence-unit name="org.jbpm.task">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/Taskorm.xml</mapping-file>
...
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jbpmdb"/>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="datos"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="datos"/>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The pattern file using the command pattern for transactions:

```
public DataAccessCommand executeCommand(DataAccessCommand c)
        throws BusinessException {
    // System.out.println("con transaccion");
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        c.setDAOFactory(daoFactory);
        try {
            c.execute();
        } catch (BusinessException e) {
            System.out.println("MESSAGE BUSINESS");
            throw new BusinessException(e.getMessage(), e,
                    e.getEnviarNotificacion());
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("MESSAGE RUNTIME " + e);
            try {
                if (transaction.isActive()) {
                    transaction.rollback();
                }
                throw new BusinessException(e, true);
            } catch (RuntimeException ex2) {
                Throwable exss = ex2;
                while (exss.getCause() != null) {
                    exss = exss.getCause();
                }
                exss.initCause(e);
                throw new BusinessException(
                        "No se pudo hacer un roll back de la transacciÃ³n",
                        ex2, true);
            }
        }
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException e) {
        if (transaction.isActive()) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        HandlerException.ProcessException(e,
                e.getStackTrace()[0].toString(), "");
        e.getSQL();
        System.out.println("e.getSQL() " + e.getSQL());
        e.getSQLException();
        System.out.println("e.getSQLException()" + e.getSQLException());
        System.out.println("e.getNextException()"
                + e.getSQLException().getNextException().getMessage());
        e.getSQLException().getNextException().getStackTrace();
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new BusinessException(e);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (transaction.isActive()) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        HandlerException.ProcessException(ex,
                ex.getStackTrace()[0].toString(), "");
        System.err.println("Error on executed command e :"
                + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new BusinessException(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return c;
}
```

Finally the file standalone.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.2">
<extensions>
 ...
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/DatosDS" pool-name="DatosPool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/datosdb</connection-url>
                <driver>postgresql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>datos</user-name>
                    <password>datos</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/jbpmDS" pool-name="JbpmPool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jbpmdb</connection-url>
                <driver>postgresql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>datos</user-name>
                    <password>datos</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
        <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" deployment-timeout="1200"/>
    </subsystem>
   ...
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>

<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
    <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
    <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
</server>
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hibernate use lazy loading approach where all the child objects are not fetched from db when you hit the query, but it will be fetched when you try to use it first time and that time session should not be closed but in your case it is closed so hibernate giving such error.

Comment: "when I have more than 3 users simultaneously connected" - sounds like a problem of sharing a resource where that should not be happening then, if that really is the criteria for triggering the problem. In the code base, is something put in a static property somewhere?

Comment: If three (3) users are working normally when you want to connect fourth sometimes leaves you, sometimes not, and if connected and performs tasks as sometimes injure others in the answers to the requests to the database or simply no longer allowed to participate by showing session is closed!

Comment: I had a similar problem caused by Classloader and more than one javassist in environment.